# LAMP is missing PHP module?

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I'm implementing some PHP code into my html bit and it seems as if PHP is not being treated as a PHP code but as a plain text instead.

I checked my PHP installation with `php -v` and it's up to date on version 7.0.

Then I looked over apache's configuration file and strangely I didn't find any lines related to PHP. I was like what the heck.

I used the keystrokes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and typed `PHP` to ensure I haven't overlooked it somewhere but nada.

What can I do?

I tried to comment out the following in `php.config` file:

```
# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /var/www/html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you installed the package `libapache2-mod-php`? (A version number may be present at the end of the package name, e.g. `libapache2-mod-php7.0` or `libapache2-mod-php5`.)

Comment: Yeah my server says it's already to the newest version. I keep searching for an answer online .....

I found this:

`# To re-enable PHP in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>`

Comment: I commented it out as this helped to somebody who had the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by following steps I found here:

https://superuser.com/questions/425181/php-code-is-returned-instead-of-executed

... where fellow developer suggested to change file's extension from .html to .php and all my code should be interpreted just fine. And it worked.